# PriorityQueue does not sort, sometime throw exception

Tags: java

I run requestor thread

```
Task t = new Task(s1, s2, c, p);

Requestor req = new Requestor(queue, t);
req.start();
```

It add task to queue and run service thread

```
queue.add(task); // my class

Service ser = new Service(queue);
ser.start();
```

add method

```
public void add(Task t) {
    synchronized (mutex) {
        queue.add(t); // PriorityQueue<Task>

        list.clear(); // DefaultListModel

        for (Task ta : queue)
            list.addElement(ta);
    }
}
```

Service's run method

```
    task = queue.pop(); // my class
...
    queue.add(task);
```

pop method

```
public Task pop() {
    synchronized (mutex) {
        ArrayList<Task> al = new ArrayList<Task>();

        Task tmp = queue.remove();
        al.add(tmp);

        while (tmp.isFinish() && !queue.isEmpty()) {
            tmp = queue.remove();
            al.add(tmp);
        }

        al.remove(al.size()-1);

        for (Task t : al) {
            queue.add(t);
        }

        list.clear();

        for (Task ta : queue)
            list.addElement(ta);

        return tmp;
    }
}
```

queue var is

```
    Comparator<Task> cmp = new TaskComparator();

    queue = new PriorityQueue<Task>(20, cmp);
```

comparator

```
 public class TaskComparator implements Comparator<Task> {

@Override
public int compare(Task o1, Task o2) {
    return o1.getPriority() - o2.getPriority();
}

}
```

generally this priority queue sort randomly, some time i can see

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:427)
at javax.swing.DefaultListModel.getElementAt(DefaultListModel.java:70)
...
```

----edit
GUI

```
private Queue queue;
...
    _add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
...
            Task t = new Task(s1, s2, c, p);

            Requestor req = new Requestor(queue, t);
            req.start();
        }
    });
...
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();

    JList _list = new JList(model);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(_list);

    queue = new Queue(model);
```

-- edit

I implements comparable to task class. If i return 1 it always add new o elements on bottom, when I return -1 it always add new element on top, but when

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Task o) {
    if (pr == o.getPriority())
        return 0;
    else if (pr > o.getPriority())
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

It sort as it want

Comment: The problem is likely in the Swing-related code, which I don't see posted here.

Comment: Update. I post important (I thing) part of GUI.java, Queue class i posted (2 method + constructor), Requestor, Service and TaskComparator posted, Task class is not inportant

Comment: PriorityQueue is not blocking. If you request an element that is null, an Exception will be thrown. You can use PriorityBlockingQueue instead.

Comment: @Stephan: I just implements, not work

Comment: PriorityBlockingQueue does not throw exception, but still not sorting correct

Comment: Please try to use a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. I think your problem depends on concurrent accesses to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PriorityQueue is a heap, and it's rebuilding when you use remove() method.

```
public void add(Task t) {
    synchronized (mutex) {
        queue.add(t);

        list.clear();

        ArrayList<Task> al = new ArrayList<Task>();

        while (queue.size() > 0)
            al.add(queue.remove());

        for (Task ta : al) {
            list.addElement(ta);
            queue.add(ta);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only method that returns a `PriorityQueue` in order is `remove()`. Iterating it does not return the elements in order. See the Javadoc.